# Partial derivatives of functions with implicit variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, chain-rule

Consider a function $f(x,y)$ with $x$ being a function of $y$, that is $f(x(y), y)$. I would like to compute the gradient of this function $\nabla f = (\partial_x f, \partial_y f)$. Using the change of derivative formula,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$ If we apply this partial derivative to the function $f$, we find
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x(y),y) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x(y),y) = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right] = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, $$
which gives an extra term  $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in addition to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. Why is there this extra term? Since $x$ is really a function of $y$, is the gradient
$$ \nabla f = (\partial_x f, \partial_y f) $$
or
$$\nabla f = (\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$$ or even
$$\nabla f = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} ) ?$$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you get confused with differentiating multivariate functions, it is often helpful to abandon the practice of giving meaningless names to variables. See, for example, pp. 44 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds (end of chapter 2) for a discussion of notation.

Comment: Your question is ill-posed. You can either ask for the gradient, treating $x$ and $y$ as independent variables, or you can compute the ($y$)-derivative of $F(y)=f(x(y),y)$. The chain rule relates the two results.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$ is given by $g(y) = (h(y),y)$ for some function $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Then our goal is to compute the derivative of $f\circ g$. By the chain rule, it is $$f'(g(y))g'(y) = \partial_1 f(g(y))h'(y)+\partial_2f(g(y))$$
, where $$\partial_1 f(g(y)) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(g(y)+he_1)-f(g(y))}{h}$$ and similarly for $\partial_2 f(g(y))$.

Comment: This is a very good answer. Is the definition of $\partial_i$ just for clarity? I interpret this as taking the usual partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ while it still has $x$ in it, and then substituting $g$.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer was posted while I was working on it so I don't have another solution but a few comments around it (too long for actual comment).

Starting with $z=f(x,y)$ and $x=h(y)$ you can just view this as $z=k(y)$ and then calculate $\frac{dz}{dy}=k'(y)$ directly; which will agree with the formula provided in the solution.

For example if $f(x,y)=x^2y$ and $x=h(y)=y^3$ then $k(y)=y^7$ and $k'(y)=7y^6$

Or using the RHS of the above solution we would get:

$k'(y) = \nabla f\cdot g'(y) = \langle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} ,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\rangle\cdot\langle h'(y),1\rangle$

$=\langle 2xy,x^2\rangle\cdot\langle3y^2,1\rangle = (2y^4)(3y^2)+y^6=7y^6$

which shows the actual gradient a little more explicitly.

Finally, this is a special case of the following standard chain rule application:

If $z=f(x,y)$ and $x=u(t), y=v(t)$ then:

$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$

Setting $x=h(y)$ and $y=t$ yields the original solution and matches the second component in the last gradient in the original post (so correct, just should have been a stand-alone derivative of a function of a single variable not part of a gradient).  This further supports the improved notation in the original solution.